# How to execute sql file with Slick 3.0.0

Tags: scala, slick

I have a structure like this

```
src
└── main
    ├── resources
    │   └── inserts.sql
    └── my.package
        └── Main.scala
```

In `Main.scala` I want to take the file `inserts.sql` and use Slick 3.0.0 to execute it on my db.

Comment: is my answer wrong? Was it helpful?

Comment: You should switch the accepted answer to either @Scalway or mine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is no way to execute a sql file with Slick other then loading it into memory as a String and executing it with `sql`, `sqlu` or `tsql`.

Beware that in this case the `$` interpolation is meant to insert bind variables into the query. To splice literal values into the query you must use `#$` instead. Since in this case the variable is the whole query, we have to do

```
val inserts_sql = Source.fromResource("inserts.sql").mkString

db.run(sqlu"#$query")
```

Comment: You should delete this answer and accept @Scalway's

Answer (score 3):

A SQL string can be executed directly by using the `SQLActionBuilder` class.

Also, since the `BufferedSource` object we get from `Source.fromResource` is `Closable`, we should wrap it with a Using block.

```
import slick.jdbc.SetParameter.SetUnit
import slick.jdbc.SQLActionBuilder

import scala.io.Source
import scala.util.Using

// ...

Using(Source.fromResource("inserts.sql")) { insertsSqlSource =>
  val sqlActionBuilder = SQLActionBuilder(insertsSqlSource.mkString, SetUnit)
  database.run(sqlActionBuilder.asUpdate)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read file content:

```scala
val query = scala.io.Source.fromResource("inserts.sql").mkString
```

and then create query using `sql` or `sqlu` interpolators:

```scala
//https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.0.0/sql.html
sql"$query".as[ExpectedType]
```

and run it as always :)

PS: Not tested. Don't have prepared env now.